# Passar informação gridlista form1 para outro gridlista no form2

Tags: c#

Bom dia,
estou quebrando a cabeça para adicionar uma linha de um grid do meu form1 para a grid do meu form2.

Abaixo segue meu código para simplificar minha dúvida.

```
ItemVendaView item = new ItemVendaView()
            {                    
                ProdutoID = produto.ProdutoId,
                CodigoBarra = produto.CodigoBarra,
                ValorVenda = produto.ValorVenda1,
                ValorCusto = produto.ValorCusto,
                Quantidade = 1,
                ProdutoDescricao = produto.DescricaoReduzida
            };                
            ITENS.Add(item);
```

esse código acima é do form principal onde quero enviar os dados do formulario de produtos para o form principal.

abaixo segue o código do formulario de produtos onde eu localizo o produto e dou um enter e envio para o form principal.

```
 private void frmProdutos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetaTituloForm("Buscar Produto");
        gridProdutos.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 11);
        gridProdutos.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        gridProdutos.DataSource = produtobll.SelecionarTodos();
        gridProdutos.Refresh();
    }
```

obrigado

Comment: Como os forms estao relacionados? Por um acaso o form1 abre o form2 ou eles ja estao previamente abertos por um outro form?